# /Main.java:15: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte byte myTotalByte=(myMinByteValue/2); ^ 1 error

Tags: java

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myMinIntValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println("MY INteger Value is =" + myMinIntValue);
        byte myMinByteValue = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println("MY byte Value is =" + myMinByteValue);

        int myTotal = (myMinIntValue);
        System.out.println(myTotal);

        byte myTotalByte = (myMinByteValue / 2);
        System.out.println(myTotalByte);

    }
}
```

ERROR:-/Main.java:15: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
    byte myTotalByte=(myMinByteValue/2);
                                    ^
1 error

Comment: cast it as a byte

Comment: It has worked when I tried to divide (myMinIntValue/2)....but not for (myMinByeValue/2)....

Comment: `byte myTotalByte = (byte) (myMinByteValue / 2);`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you do it making `byte` type variable as `final` :

```
final byte myMinByteValue = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
```

**Or** you can `cast` it to `byte` and let the compiler know explicitly.

```
byte myTotalByte = (byte) (myMinByteValue / 2);
```

To know more please visit the java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

Answer (score 0):

The `2`is of type `int`, you have to cast it:

```
byte myTotalByte = myMinByteValue / (byte)2;
```

That's iirc, as I'm not at a computer right now.

Comment: It will not works either and will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 byte myTotalByte = (byte)(myMinByteValue / 2);
```

`2` is an integer literal, so the result is also an integer. But even if you write `myMinByteValue / (byte)2` - it will be still an integer, because `int` is the minimal type size in JVM (`byte` is treated as `int` on JVM internals).